# prolog, probably some race condition

Tags: prolog

just to practice prolog, I am solving a few puzzles using it and I ran into some very weird behavior of prolog.

The full code may be found here https://github.com/bibiki/AdventOfCode2022/blob/main/day14/solution.pl

The interesting part is this

```
start_a_grid( Xlength, Ylength, Result ) :-
  give_me( Ylength, air, Row ),
  give_me( Xlength, Row, Result ).

give_me( 0, V, [] ).
give_me( N, V, [V|Rest] ) :-
    write(N), nl,
    N1 is N - 1,
    give_me(N1, V, Rest).
```

Now, if I run `start_a_grid(535, 169, Grid)` it works fine, I get a Grid. If, I however, run `start_a_grid(535, 169, Cave), input(Lines), init(Lines, Cave, Initialized).` then N in my give_me predicate goes below 0. From my experiemnts, it is the inclusion of init predicate in my query that causes the problem.

`start_a_grid(13, 11, Cave), sample_lines(Lines), init(Lines, Cave, Initialized)` works perfectly fine.

My swipl version is 'SWI-Prolog version 8.4.2 for x86_64-linux'. Am I missing something or is this rather a bug in my swipl version? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: hmmmm... probably my Lines, or my manipulation of it, calls give_me with a negative number!!! but, no. start_a_grid is the only rule that relies on give_me!!!

Comment: You probably want to add a cut: `give_me(0, V, []) :- !.` to actually *stop* at zero, rather than keep going into negative numbers.

Comment: there are two queries, that are pretty much the same, except for arguments, yet one of them has N going below 0 and the other does not have that. Now, if I add that cut as you suggested, It prevents N from going below 0 in both cases, but it remains unclear why it works without it for a particular combination of arguments.

Comment: It will become clear if you use e.g. `trace` to step through your program, to see exactly what is happening - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger    If negative numbers are undesirable, can add e.g. `N > 0` before `N1 is N - 1`

Comment: if instead of start_a_grid(535, 169, Cave) i call start_a_grid(169, 535, Cave), it seems to work better. yet, I do not see why calling init with start_a_grid(535, 169, Cave) gets N to go below 0. with all I know at present, I am speculating that start_a_grid(535, 169, Cave) does not build Cave before its values are needed. and init attempts to access positions in Cave with negative coordinates, and this calls give_me with some negative N. something like that.